# Conda 23.3.1: what shall be the content of build.sh?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I found `grayskull` for creating `meta.yml` files and I found [this github action](https://github.com/MichaelsJP/conda-package-publish-action) for publishing on conda.

However, said github action require a build.sh file and according to [the official guide](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/stable/user-guide/tutorials/build-pkgs.html?highlight=build.sh#writing-the-build-script-files-build-sh-and-bld-bat) such a file must contain "...the text exactly as shown:"

```
$PYTHON setup.py install     # Python command to install the script.
```

Nevertheless, newest project have `pyproject.toml` and I am not sure the above guide applies today since it is fairly old, apparently.

As for conda 23.3.1, what shall be the content of said `build.sh`?

**EDIT:** The question has been closed due to that it has been considered opinion-based.

Unfortunately, it is not, as the following Theorem shows.

*Theorem: The question is NOT opinion based.*

**Proof**: By contradiction assume that the question is opinion based. Then, there should not exist any non-opinion based guide explaining what shall be included in build.sh. However, an official, non-opinion based guide exists and it is [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/build-scripts.html), which contradicts the initial hypothesis. Hence, the question is not opinion-based. **QED**

Comment: This is phrased in an opinion-prone way and given how diverse packages can be, I doubt has a narrow answer. I would regard whatever Conda Forge does to be the state of the art, so if you want to get a sense of what passes on there, then browse through [the recent accepted recipes](https://github.com/conda-forge/staged-recipes/pulls?q=is%3Apr+is%3Amerged+). Note that most simple Python packages just use `{{ PYTHON }} -m pip install . -vv --no-deps --no-build-isolation` inline in the `meta.yaml` - no `build.sh` needed.

Comment: The other problem is that phrasing the question this way makes it inherently prone to going out-of-date. We're trying to build a long-lived knowledge base here, where people in future years can come back and still benefit from answers. (By contrast: if instead of "in 2023" one asked about "with Conda <version>", that would still remain valid forever, even when that version is no longer current)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `We're trying to build a long-lived knowledge base here` can you point me to any official stack overflow page where this is clearly stated? Because otherwise it is in-fact your comment to be opinion based.

Comment: @merv Theorem: the question is NOT opinion based. Proof: by contradiction assume that the question is opinion based. That would imply that there should not exist any guide explaining what shall be included in build.sh. However, a guide exists and it is here: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/build-scripts.html  which prove the Theorem.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  I updated the question by writing the conda version rather than the year but regardless of that,  in your time-reasoning there may be a logic fallacy that would contribute to decrease knowledge rather than increasing it. You may want to correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a sort of answer triggered by the comment I received that pushed me in searching towards the right direction.

I decided to share my learnings (that may not be 100% accurate) that I hope will give some insights on how the `conda` package machinery work.

The way to go today (2023) is `grayskull`, that I mentioned also before.
That tool generate `meta.yml` files starting from `pypi` packages (and not only from `pypi`, you can even use a `sdist` as a staring point, see `grayskull` docs).

If your package is pure python code (plus some data eventually), then the `meta.yml` generated from `grayskull` contain all the information needed for building your conda package.
You should edit such `meta.yml` file a bit though, for example you should edit the `recipe-mainteiner` field. Then you can run `conda build` and you should get your conda package.

In reality, things are a bit more complex.

In-fact, in order to make a conda package you need a *recipe*.
What's that?
A recipe is a folder that contains a `meta.yml` a `build.sh` and a `bld.bat` files at least, plus some optional files such as `run_test.[py,pl,sh,bat]` where you specify how your package shall be tested.
A recipe can also include patches files and resources like icons, etc.

But what is the purpose of these additional `build.sh`, etc.  files?

Well, if your package has more than python code but include e.g.  additional code written in other languages, then you should explain how such code shall be processed. For example, if in addition to python code you have some C source code. In in the `build.sh` you specify (among other things) how such C code shall be compiled. No need to say that you cannot pre-compile it because then the compiled code would be platform specific. The same principle applies to `tests`: you may add a `run_test.[py,pl,sh,bat]` where you specify how you package shall be tested.

However, for what I understood, if the build process of your package is only made of few lines and the tests are rather straightforward, then you can *inline* such info by using the Section `build` and `tests` of the `meta.yml` file instead of having separated `build.sh`, etc. files.

Note that in the easiest case of pure python source code, as mentioned in a comment, you have that `build` is just

```
{{ PYTHON }} -m pip install . -vv
```

whereas `test` is just :

```
import your_package
```

which is exactly how `grayskull` fill up such fields in the `meta.yml` when you generate it from `pypi`.
Now that such info is included in the `meta.yml` file you don't need any `build.sh, bld.bat` and `run_tests` files.

Examples of recipes can be found, as already pointed out in a comment, [here](https://github.com/conda-forge/staged-recipes/pulls?q=is%3Apr%20is%3Amerged%20) whereas a guide for conda recipe can be found [here.](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/stable/concepts/recipe.html) - but still, it is from 2018.

In summary, the great thing of conda, for what I understood, is that it can package stuff written in different languages.

But there is more: it seems that conda handles dependencies better than other tools (again, for what I read, so take it with a grain of salt).

However, there have been many complains about its speed, and that is true. It is terribly slow in its default setting. However, you can install [libmamba](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/a-faster-conda-for-a-growing-community) that speed up things drastically - and that I can confirm that it's true.

I hope that this summary is not too wrong and it should answer the initial question on what should be in the build.sh file.